# unable to set socket.io to listen in IPv4

Tags: javascript, java, express, socket.io

I am trying to setup IPV4 in Socket.IO, I am gettng this error:

```
/var/www/js/AndroRAT/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:279
  opts.path = opts.path || this.path();
        ^

TypeError: Cannot create property 'path' on string '0.0.0.0'
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (/var/www/js/AndroRAT/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:279:13)
    at new Server (/var/www/js/AndroRAT/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:59:17)
    at Function.Server [as listen] (/var/www/js/AndroRAT/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:44:41)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/js/AndroRAT/index.js:28:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Why would Socket.IO listen in IPV6 in the first place?

Comment: Logs show node package error. Can you share your Javascript configuration file for Socket.IO

Comment: when i try to add 0.0.0.0 it crashes. but when i remove it, it work fine :
const
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    IO = require('socket.io'),
    CONST = require('./includes/const');

global.CONST = CONST;

let client_io = IO.listen(CONST.control_port,'0.0.0.0');

client_io.sockets.pingInterval = 30000;

Comment: Can you share whole file, for better context

Comment: pasted in here >>> https://pastebin.com/SHbS16Wv

Answer (score 0):

1. Your assumption regarding `0.0.0.0` being IPV6 is wrong. `0.0.0.0` is IPV4 address. Could you search in your workspace for `0.0.0.0`(Given that it is defined in your code) and change that to `127.0.0.1`.
2. According to Socket.IO docs, `IO.listen` takes only port number.

[Documentation Link](https://socket.io/docs/)

```
const IO = require('socket.io')(server);
let client_io = IO.listen(CONST.control_port);
```

Comment: 1. actually, i tried to put 0.0.0.0 in order to make scoket listen in IPv4, it's not my assumption that 0.0.0.0 is IPv6, which is actually so wrong 2. Got it. 3. tried that, it's still listening in IPv6. 4. :/var/www/js/AndroRAT$ npm -v socket.io >>> 6.14.4

Comment: Try to change to `IO.listen(CONST.control_port, '127.0.0.1');` for IPV4 localhost

Comment: tried that, and it has the same error as above. but instead of '0.0.0.0' i get '127.0.0.1'

Comment: Checl the documentation link.